# Find out closing balance and opening balance from employee table

Tags: sql

Below is my table data

```
       id   in  out part date
       1    20  10  1   2005-02-02
       2    10  30  1   2005-02-03
       3    20  50  2   2005-02-04
       4    20  30  3   2005-02-05
       5    100 10  3   2005-02-06
       6    20  2   2   2005-02-07
```

My opening balance condition is

> if I select date range 2 to 7 then opening balance 
>            sum of (in) form 2 to 7 - sum of (out) from 2 to 6

Comment: what does part mean in you table?

Comment: Which DataBase are you using ? MSSQL, Mysql, oracle

Comment: @Matt I think "part" is another name the so called "date range". I think he gives each date a integer value representing ... something related to the dates (maybe time slices?)

Comment: its part id i want group by part id

Comment: Please edit your question and add the expected output from your query. You also need to tell is which DBMS (Postgres, Oracle, ...) you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group with SUM

```
SELECT part, 
SUM(in)-(SELECT SUM(a.out) FROM yourtable a WHERE a.date BETWEEN '2005-02-02' AND '2005-02-06' AND a.part = part) AS OpeningBalance, 
SUM(in)-SUM(out) AS ClosingBalance
FROM yourtable
WHERE date BETWEEN '2005-02-02' AND '2005-02-07'
GROUP BY part
```

Output:

```
part OpeningBalance ClosingBalance
1    -100           -10
2    -90            -12
3    -10            80
```

SQL FIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/747c0f/8/0

(in the fiddle i used the names ina and outa as in and out are reserved words.

Comment: if i select date range 2 to 7 then
opening balance  = (sum of in from 2 to 7) - (sum of out from 2 to 6)

Comment: Updated answer for you